# Xamarin preload WebView in a TabbedPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app with a TabbedPage as the application's main page.
The TabbedPage has two pages, one is a NavigationPage and the other is a ContentPage with a WebView control.

When the app loads the NatigationPage is the active page, but I need to meanwhile preload the WebView.

The WebView however starts navigation only once the platform renderer is created and that happens only after activating its page (changing the active tab) for the first time.

Is there a way to activate that page without actually navigating to it?

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry** , that's designed for mobile to save memory. You can not make the invisble page to load webview in background .

**First** , [Tabbed page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page#create-a-tabbedpage) has also created each pages when running , just not rendering them until page is visible .

[image]

**Second**, suggesting using [Events](http://Navigating%20%E2%80%93%20event%20raised%20when%20the%20WebView%20begins%20loading%20a%20new%20page.%20Navigated%20%E2%80%93%20event%20raised%20when%20the%20page%20is%20loaded%20and%20navigation%20has%20stopped.) of `WebView` to increase the experience for user .

- **Navigating** – event raised when the WebView begins loading a new page.
- **Navigated** – event raised when the page is loaded and navigation has stopped.

You can load a preview view before webview be visible , that's be recommanded by official suggestion.

For example , showing a loading `Label` to tell customer , `WebView` is loading .And make `Label` invisible after `WebView` loaded . (Also can customer other views ,such as `Image` , `Video`,`Gif` ,etc)

```
void webviewNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    labelLoading.IsVisible = true;
}

void webviewNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    labelLoading.IsVisible = false;
}
```